# How to check if a column (of type array) contains a value in SQL (without ANY)?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

I have a SQL table on `table` in which one of the columns, `arr`, is an array of integers. How do I filter the table to rows in which the arrays under `arr` contain an integer value? (e.g. if I search for 1, then the arrays [1,2,3] and [1,4] should be included, but [3,4] should not).

I'm using Spark on Databricks and don't have access to the ANY or MEMBER OF functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use `array_contains` method:

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from table where array_contains(arr, 1)")
```